# How to express a set of labeled elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have a set of matrices $A=\{\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{Y}, \boldsymbol{Z}\}$. Each matrix has a meaning according to its name such that another set $B=\{\boldsymbol{X'}, \boldsymbol{Z'}\}$ would stablish a correspondence between $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{X'}$ and between $\boldsymbol{Z}$ and $\boldsymbol{Z'}$.
However, the sets themselves don't know anything about the name of the matrices, and even if they had the same size, there is no ordering in sets to make a correspondence.
The best I could do was to put some kind of a literal together with each matrix, but it doesn't seem correct, since it refers to variables, not a proper label:

$B'=\{\langle x,\boldsymbol{X'} \rangle, \langle z, \boldsymbol{Z'} \rangle\}$

I am avoding replacing the set by a sequence, because there would be an ugly "empty" element in the middle of $B$:

$B''=\langle\boldsymbol{X'}, \emptyset, \boldsymbol{Z'}\rangle$

And it wouldn't be possible to easily unite two "groups" like this: $B \cup \{\boldsymbol{Y}\}$ or like this: $B' \cup \{\langle y, \boldsymbol{Y} \rangle \}$.

EDIT

More context: we have a function $f_1$ that transforms $B=\{\boldsymbol{X'}, \boldsymbol{Z'}\}$ by adding a matrix to it, depending on the given matrices: $f_1(B)=\{\boldsymbol{X'}, \boldsymbol{Y'}, \boldsymbol{Z'}\}$ or by modifying some of the matrices:
$f_2(B)=\{\boldsymbol{X''}, \boldsymbol{Z'}\}$.

Different $f$s can be used, to perform different transformations. Although, $f_i$ is a physical/computational process that will not be formally defined. It just exists.
Sometimes it will be useful to show that $f_1(B) = B \cup \{ \boldsymbol{Y'} \}$.

Comment: Could we have more context here? What are you trying to do with these matrices?

Comment: Why not use a sequence with two elements for $B$ and define an operation $\langle X',Z'\rangle\mathrel{\bar\cup} Y=\langle X',Y,Z'\rangle$? As the order *does* matter, using sets instead of sequences seems like the worse choice.

Comment: @LukeCollins More context added.

Comment: @Vsotvep More context added.